# Android: Cannot see file saved on external storage

Tags: android, storage, external

```
public void write(View view)
{
    String state;

    File Dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    if (!Dir.exists())
    {
        Dir.mkdir();
    }
    File file = new File(Dir,"nahk.txt");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String Message = "5nahk";
    try {
        FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(file);
        FOS.write(Message.getBytes());
        FOS.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have added write permission in the manifest xml file. This method is called when I press a button. The toast says that the txt file is saved in the Download folder of my Internal Storage (since I don't have an SD card in my LG G3). I open the file location (using FileManager on my LG G3) and there is no "nahk.txt" in that folder. Why can't I see the file?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply guys. I figured it out. I was developing on marshmallow, which requires you to ask the user for permission before using external storage, in addition to the permission being asked in the manifest file. In short, the java code needs to have a request for external storage permission for marshmallow. If anyone needs help, i can provide links.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with native android development but I encountered something similar using cordova. After saving a file the file was not visible browsing with a usb cable but it was actually there. To see it had to restart my device.

So you could try to restart your device and check if it is still invisible (or create a method which fetches or checks the existence of the saved file to check if it is there).

edit: I learned this by googling so you should find it also

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
File Dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Your_Folder_Name";
File file = new File(Dir,"nahk.txt");
```

this file will save inside of your device storage Your_Folder_Name